# Improve performance on BigDecimal to double conversion

Tags: java, performance, double, bigdecimal

This is the Jdk7-b147 version of [`BigDecimal.doubleValue()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.toString%28%29)

```
public double doubleValue(){
  if (scale == 0 && intCompact != INFLATED)
    return (double)intCompact;
  // Somewhat inefficient, but guaranteed to work.
  return Double.parseDouble(this.toString());
}
```

They admit that this way is inefficient! Is there a better/faster way than to use this method?

Comment: Accuracy is pretty crucial, and the logic to convert a `BigDecimal` to a `double` is _hard_.  (That said, I've got a JDK patch pending review to speed up `BigInteger.doubleValue()` by a little over two orders of magnitude.)

Comment: Awesome! Do you have a link to the patch?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/attachment.cgi?id=254&action=diff is the patch to optimize `BigInteger.{float,double}Value()`. The logic for `Double.parseDouble`, which is nearly the same as what you'd need to convert `BigDecimal` to `double`, is in [`sun.misc.FloatingDecimal`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html) -- you can see how messy it is there.

Comment: Louis, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you make these comments into an answer, I'll checkmark you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a much better way to convert a `BigDecimal` to a `double`.  This is because the algorithms to convert `foo * 10^bar` to `baz * 2^quux` efficiently, while keeping very specific rounding semantics, are extremely nasty and unpleasant -- see [`sun.misc.FloatingDecimal`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html) for details, or read [this paper](ftp://ftp.ccs.neu.edu/pub/people/will/howtoread.ps).

`BigInteger.doubleValue()`, on the other hand, *does* have lots of opportunities for optimization, since it needn't deal with decimal fractions, but only integers.  I have a [JDK patch pending](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/814759462705) that optimizes `BigInteger.doubleValue()` by slightly more than two orders of magnitude, though it's still awaiting review.

**Update:** The fix was added in OpenJDK 8, made available to the general public on March 18, 2014.

Comment: @LouisWasserman did they remove the "voting for bugs" thing they used to have awhile back? I found [this](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7131192), I notice it hasn't been updated since July. Do you have more information on WHEN they will look at it?